# Goldstone theorem in Schwartz

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

On page 566, Schwartz’s QFT book, to see the $\pi$ is the Goldstone boson, it reads:
$$J^\mu=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \pi)} \frac{\delta \pi}{\delta \theta}=F_\pi \partial_\mu \pi \tag{28.15}$$
$$\langle\Omega|J^\mu(x)|\pi(p)\rangle=ip^\mu F_\pi e^{-ipx} \tag{28.16}$$
My question is:

- in the first equation, how is $\frac{\delta \pi}{\delta \theta}=F_\pi$ derived from the symmetry translation $\pi(x) \rightarrow \pi(x)+F_\pi \theta$ ?
- how to derive the second equation?

My attempt to the second equation:
$$\langle \Omega|J^\mu(x)|\pi(p)\rangle=
F_\pi \langle \Omega|\partial_\mu\pi \pi|\Omega\rangle$$
Substitute $\pi=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}[a_p e^{-ipx}+a_p^\dagger e^{ipx}]$ into it, I get

$$F_\pi \langle \Omega| \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}[a_p (-ip^\mu)e^{-ipx}+a_p^\dagger (ip^\mu)e^{ipx}]  \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_k}}[a_k e^{-ikx}+a_k^\dagger e^{ikx}] |\Omega\rangle$$
$$=F_\pi \langle \Omega| \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}[a_p (-ip^\mu)e^{-ipx}]  \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_k}}[a_k^\dagger e^{ikx}] |\Omega\rangle$$
$$=F_\pi \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_k}}e^{-i(p-k)x}\langle \Omega|a_p(-ip^\mu)a_k^\dagger |\Omega\rangle$$
$$=F_\pi( -ip^\mu) \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega_k}}e^{-i(p-k)x}(2\pi)^3\delta^3(p-k)$$

$$=F_\pi( -ip^\mu) \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega_p}$$

Comment: What do you mean by your first question? It is a product of the two functional derivatives evaluated from (28.13,14). Do you wish to edit it out?

Comment: Have you heeded (28.8)? Have you commuted the annihilator to the right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I know how to do the  functional derivative with $L$, but to do the other, I don’t know how a symmetry transformation leads to a derivative. If it’s simply $\pi(x)=F_\pi \theta$, then $\frac{\delta \pi}{\delta \theta}=F_\pi$.

Comment: Ughhhh! The symmetry transformation *means*, informally,  $\pi \mapsto \pi + \delta\pi = \pi + F \theta.$  Often there are higher terms in $\theta$, but one keeps the linear term to lowest order. Your instructor has failed to detail this?

Comment: @CosmasZachos -i consider (28.8) merely as a constructed state defined as Goldstone bosons, and (28.9) gives a way to identify it. It’s not necessarily the same state mentioned in the following example,(so we are now trying to identity it). -I haven’t. I just let the terms with creation operator to the bra and anihilation operator to the ket vanish.

Comment: ...so when you do this there is only a delta function that survives, and....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks a lot for your help!! I still have a little more problem with that and I edited the question. Would you please take a moment to check it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do normalizations... Matt does them in sec 2.3.1. Make sure you understand those of the commutator of a scalar field with its canonical momentum, which is basically what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first equation, consider an infinitesimal transformation, $\pi(x) \rightarrow \pi(x)+F_\pi \delta \theta$. We have $\delta \pi(x) = F_\pi \delta \theta$, so $\frac{\delta \pi(x)}{\delta \theta}= F_\pi$.

For the second equation, your first mistake is on equating $|\pi(p)\rangle$ with $\pi|\Omega\rangle$. $\pi$ is a field, not a single creation operator.

To derive that result, you just need to show that since $|\pi(p)\rangle$ is defined to be the state created by the $\pi$ field, $\langle \Omega |\pi(x)|\pi(p)\rangle=e^{-ipx}$. Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \Omega |J^\mu(x)|\pi(p)\rangle= & F_\pi\langle \Omega |\partial^\mu\pi(x)|\pi(p)\rangle \\
=&F_\pi \partial^\mu e^{-ipx} \\
=&-ip^\mu F_\pi e^{-ipx}.
\end{align}
$$